# Subtotal with >1 criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to subtotal count of 2 criteria?

Ex. as per the image:

[image]

I want subtotal count of "LONG" in "G" column & "Net P/L" should be >0 Both criteria need to be satisfied =Subtotal "LONG" & "profit >0"

I want the count of only filtered rows by using SUBTOTAL formula.
I Found formula for one criteria like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]]="LONG")*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[Long/Short]],ROW(Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]])-MIN(ROW(Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]])),0))))
```

But I want Subtotal for 2 Criteria (Long & P/L >0)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]]="LONG")*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[Long/Short]],ROW(Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]])-MIN(ROW(Table1[[#All],[Long/Short]])),0))))
```

Comment: Just add in another multiplication similar to the first part: `(Table1[[P/L]]>0)*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G3:G5000="LONG")*(V3:V5000>0)*SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(V2,ROW(V3:V5000)-ROW(V2),)))
```

The 103 in SUBTOTAL will exclude filtered rows.

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell and then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to create the array formula.